# Vue2: data updated but html not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue and with the help of the docs and the Vue community on S.O. I have been making progress in learning how to make more complicated components.

This question is in regards to a custom select component, where the data for the selected option is correct, but the displayed HTML is not. I am providing a M.W.E.; however, this only occurs for me when the custom select component is nested through several other components.

I know this is a lot of code, so the M.W.E. is provided via [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w0013q3vmw), where each component is in it's own file (making it easier to read).

**Description of component**

[image]

The component is meant to be an advanced data filter, that accepts an object that simulates a database, e.g. each key is a the "id" of its corresponding value ("record"). It then allows one to filter on the keys (properties / fields) of the record.

Thus we have the top-most component `AdvancedFilterTable`. This table allows the user to dynamically add and remove filters `AdvancedFilterRows`.

A filter row houses 5 simple components:

- logic: is the filter and / or (`AdvancedFilterSelectLogic`)
- function: what to be applied to the field (`AdvancedFilterSelectFunction`)
- property: which field to filter on (`AdvancedFilterSelectProperty`)
- conditional: what test to apply to each records afore set field (`AdvancedFilterSelectConditional`)
- value: the value to test in the conditional (`AdvancedFilterInput`)

e.g.

`{logic: 'and', function: 'identity', property: 'x', conditional: 'gt', value: 5}`

The feature that I added which introduced the bug is dynamic options for `AdvancedFilterSelectFunction` and `AdvancedFilterSelectConditional` based on the type of `AdvancedFilterSelectProperty`.

e.g. if the selected property is `x`, where the corresponding value thereof is an array of numbers, then an option in`AdvancedFilterSelectFunction` should include "mean", "max", etc and `AdvancedFilterSelectConditional` should include "includes", "not includes", etc. However, if "mean" is selected (applying the function to the property changes its type) then the conditionals should change again (this time dropping "includes" and "not includes").

In the MWE provided, I have the following dummy data:

```
let records = {
  a: { x: 1, y: "a string", z: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  b: { x: 2, y: "strange?", z: [1, 2, 4] },
  c: { x: 3, y: "starts w", z: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  d: { x: 10, y: "some let", z: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] },
  e: { x: 2, y: "? qwerty", z: [1, 40] }
};
```

Where the type of x is number, y is string, and z in array number.

**How to produce bug**

1. open the mwe [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w0013q3vmw)
   [image]
2. click the green plus icon to add a new filter

[image]

3. click the property select and change x to z

[image]

Checking the components, all the corresponding data is set correctly.
This is further emphasized as the function select and the conditional select have dynamically changes to include options specific to array type data.

Nonetheless, the select still shows 'x'.  Trying to then select 'x' to reset the selection does not work as it is still selected to x...

The custom select's all pass their data through the different encapsulating components as outlined in [Vue2: handling multi-child prop synchronization with models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882537/vue2-handling-multi-child-prop-synchronization-with-models) 
with the answer's fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/ejq86c73/9/

solution: https://61qky5y6mr.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select inputs don't actually have any model associated with them, so the value is never shown, it's broadcast though. However since you're using props to delegate the value juggling from the parent, you actually need a computed property to handle this, something like this:

```
computed: {
  selectedVal: {
    get() {
      return this.selected
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$emit('updateSelected', value)
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply that to your select (at least the AdvancedFilterSelectProperty component):

```
<select v-model="selectedVal">
```

There's no need for the `@input` function here as our `setter` is `$emitting` to our parent when we select an `<option>` as the value is changing

Comment: If it isnt too much work, may I ask for you to fork the example and put this in? I am just a bit confused as to exactly where it goes and how to use. In the Vue docs they suggest specifying a custom model via `model: {prop: <prop>, event:<event>}` and I am not sure why it must be so much work to have top level access to nested component values. I would think it would be feasible with the `.sync` modifier, but I can not get it to work and their example with event name `'update:title'` does not work for me :/

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? (both the data syncing and the organization of components). I am new to Vue and I figured this was the right delegation of components, but perhaps I am mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

In `AdvancedFilterSelectProperty.vue`, you have a prop `selected`. That changes as the user changes the selection. But, the selected property of the `<select />` element itself is checking the expression `key == value`

The `value` comes from `data` of the component. The `data` does not update when the user changes the selection, but `selected` prop certainly does.

So, instead of checking against `value` in `data`, check against `selected` prop.

```
<select @change='updateSelected($event)'>
    <option
        v-for='(val, key) in options'
        :value='key'
        :key="key"
        :selected='key == selected'
    >
        {{val.text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

That solves your issue.

Check working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/38vlwq4yx6

Comment: This correct, so +1, but a perhaps better solution is updated the `updateSelect` function to include `this.value = event.target.value;`

Comment: Not sure, why have two properties that indicate the same thing. value and selected. Just keep one source of truth, easier to reason about.

Comment: Also, check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components. I did not go through your entire setup. So not sure if this is applicable for you. But whenever I am making components like AdvancedFilterSelectProperty.vue, I also use v-model on such components.

Comment: I would prefer to have just one but in a previous question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853417/vue2-passing-function-as-prop-triggers-warning-that-prop-is-already-set I learned that Vue does not like prop mutated by the component

Comment: AS for the v-model on components, I did read that and hence the custom `@input` function `updateSelect` as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: In order to use v-model on a component, you should take in a value prop and emit a custom input event. Both which you are not doing yet. So, on input event of the select element, you would have to emit your own input event. Then, <advanced-filter-select-property v-model="something" /> can be used, which is even more declarative.

Comment: I do emit a custom input event, I just wrap it in a method `updateSelected` so that it is cleaner. As for the use of a prop and a data element, that is because of the linked quesiton, where v-model works if the component is only nested once, but not more than once.

Comment: You are emitting updateSelected event. this.$emit("updateSelected", event.target.value);

Comment: Yeah, like the docs `:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173643/discussion-between-prashant-and-sumneuron).